# Doctrine ResultSetMappingBuilder Join Same Entity Two times

Tags: sql, database, join, orm, doctrine

I want to implement a Join on Same entity 2 times on 2 different associated fields with 2 tables.
but it seems addJoinedEntityFromClassMetadata () Does not support it?

For e.g. I want to specify same Entity class parameter 2 times with different alias.

addJoinedEntityFromClassMetadata("Entity\User","u1".....) and addJoinedEntityFromClassMetadata("Entity\User","u2".....) and

Please suggest if it is supported.

Answer (score 0):

of course it's supported .

You have to set different aliases to your entities, et specify aliases for duplicated column like this :

```
 addJoinedEntityFromClassMetadata('Entity\User', 'user1', OKey, array ( 'id' => 'user1id' ));
 addJoinedEntityFromClassMetadata('Entity\User', 'user2', OKey, array ( 'id' => 'user2id' ));
```

*** Okey is the name of the relationship column on your root entity